# Filling the Profile on CreatedUser event gets: This property cannot be set for anonymous users.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, profile

I am trying to fill the `Profile` properties with data from user, just after singing up to the website.

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="center SignUp">
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard" runat="server" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard_CreatedUser">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
</div>
</form>
```

Code behind: `OnCreatedUser` event

```
protected void CreateUserWizard_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser newUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard.UserName);
    Profile.UserName = newUser.UserName;     // Get and Set the user name after sign up.
    Guid Id = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey; // Get the UserId after sign up.
    Profile.UserId = Id;                     // Set the UserId after sign up.
}
```

After filling the data and clicking "Create User". I get:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> This property cannot be set for anonymous users.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException:
>   This property cannot be set for anonymous users.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 40:         } Line 41:         set { Line 42:
>   this.SetPropertyValue("UserName", value); Line 43:         } Line 44: 
>   }
>
> Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\root\b2622a96\eb730107\App_Code.ef53d8ra.4.cs    Line:
>   42
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ProviderException: This property cannot be set for anonymous users.] 
>   System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.SetInternal(String propertyName, Object
>   value) +2383575    System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.set_Item(String
>   propertyName, Object value) +80
>   System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase.SetPropertyValue(String propertyName,
>   Object propertyValue) +13    ProfileCommon.set_UserName(String value)
>   in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\b2622a96\eb730107\App_Code.ef53d8ra.4.cs:42
>   SignUp.CreateUserWizard_CreatedUser(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\BegASPNET\FacebookCorrectReation\SignUp.aspx.cs:18
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnCreatedUser(EventArgs e)
>   +116    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.AttemptCreateUser() +342    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs
>   e) +110    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +401
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +119
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardChildTable.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +16
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>   +37    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +114    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +252
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line at the beaning of the `CreateUserWizard_CreatedUser` event handler:

`Profile.Initialize(CreateUserWizard.UserName,true);` So that it becomes:

```
protected void CreateUserWizard_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        Profile.Initialize(CreateUserWizard.UserName,true);
        MembershipUser newUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard.UserName);
        Profile.UserName = newUser.UserName;     // Get and Set the user name after sign up.
        Guid Id = (Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey; // Get the UserId after sign up.
        Profile.UserId = Id;                     // Set the UserId after sign up.
    }
}
```